# Toggle scroll class on all pages except one

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, I have a transparent nav bar which on scroll turns white and the logo changes from white to black.

This works as it should, but my issue is that on one specific page I have (/toursearch) I am using a white background for my nav and would like to only show the black logo. But the scroll class is still being applied and causing me issues.

So my questions is, how would I target all other pages except the tour search page?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed nofocus" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div class="logo-desk d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png" class="img-fluid" /></a>
        </div>
        <!-- END LOGO -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item all-tours">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/toursearch">Tours</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/destinations">Destinations<span class="mob-menu-icon float-right d-sm-block d-lg-none"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us">About Us<span class="mob-menu-icon float-right d-sm-block d-lg-none"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/teaching-resources">Resources <span class="mob-menu-icon float-right d-sm-block d-lg-none"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-light");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `tour` page a specific class at the top, eg

```
<body class='tourpage'>
```

then set your css accordingly:

```
.navbar-light .logo-desk { background-color: white; } 
.tourpage .navbar-light .logo-desk { background-color: black }

.navbar-light.scrolled .logo-desk  { background-color: black }
.tourpage .navbar-light.scrolled .logo-desk  { background-color: white }
```

(change css selectors / colours to match your specific needs, bit hard to tell without your current css, but the principle remains the same).

Comment: Once adding a class to `body` tag, you can modify your jQuery selector to achieve your result. Modify it as `var $nav = $("body:not(.tourpage) .navbar-light");`

Comment: @Jishad this is a good addition.  Taking this route, it would be better to make it reusable/generic name, eg `.no-nav-scroll` `$("body:not(.no-nav-scroll) .navbar-light")` then it can be applied to any page in the future.